# Memory leaking for NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents

Tags: swift, memory-leaks

Greetings: Instruments is telling me that I have memory leaks (3 Bytes a-piece) from the two addLocalMonitor calls in viewDidLoad.  I am happy to be shown my error(s) and why this is (may be) leaking.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Environment:

- Swift: 4
- Xcode: 9.4
- Deployment Target: 10.11

### Code

```
override func keyDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
        nextResponder?.keyDown(with: theEvent)

        let hasCommand = theEvent.modifierFlags.contains(.command)

        switch theEvent.charactersIgnoringModifiers! {
        case "q" where hasCommand == true:  // Capture "Command-Q"
            let app = NSApplication.shared
            app.terminate(NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) { [unowned self] (theEvent) -> NSEvent? in
            self.keyDown(with: theEvent)
            return theEvent
        }

        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .flagsChanged) { [unowned self] (theEvent) -> NSEvent? in
            self.flagsChanged(with: theEvent)
            return theEvent
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that stumbles upon this, as usual - the presenting leak is usually a symptom of something else, somewhere else.  Turns out I had missed an [unowned self] buried in a closure elsewhere.  Once that was remedied, this "leak" went away.  Needle - meet haystack.

Bottom line: The syntax followed above is not in-error.